# Javascript not working inside form tag in ASP master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created a simple menu in an ASP master page and when I use the form tag, JavaScript stops working:

```html
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: check the browser console for errors - with this code we just unable to locate any possible error or bug

Comment: No error when I'm removing <form> tag it is working perfectly

Comment: Is your script contained within <asp:Content>...</asp:Content> tags?